# Fourier transform of the critical line of zeta?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory

Is there a known expression for the (distributional) Fourier transform of the Riemann zeta function, taken along the critical line?

I'd love to say that it's a weighted sum  of delta distributions, logarithmically spaced and decreasing in amplitude, as in

$\sum_n \frac{\delta(\omega-\log(n))}{n^{1/2}}$

but this fails to be a tempered distribution, and fails in general when the exponent in the denominator is less than 1.

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/225327/fourier-transform-of-the-critical-line-of-zeta